# Import error with python gmond_python_modules in Ganglia

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos, ganglia

I used [gmond_python_modules](https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/tree/master/gpu/nvidia), trying to monitor one cluster having several hosts with each has 8 GPUs.

And after the last steps, I tried to restart gmond service on my web node, only to get:

```
Starting GANGLIA gmond: Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
                                                           [FAILED]
```

I searched and thought initially it was because I compiled ganglia without `--with-python` option. But it wasn't. I recompiled with that option(checked configure output and it saied it found python) and everything works fine until I added GPU monitoring python module. Same error again.

And I also tried to manually assign `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH`, which makes no difference.  I installed anaconda. Is it a possible reason that causes Ganglia not finding correct load path?

Any thoughts are welcome. And will offer more details if needed.

Distribution and version details:
System: centos 6.8
Python: 2.7 on web node, 2.6 on computing node
Ganglia: 3.7.2
gmond_python_modules: clone form Github today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this post](http://maciek.lasyk.info/sysop/2013/11/10/adding-python-support-for-ganglia-gmond-on-centos-rhel/). The reason here is `python-devel` is not installed in calculating nodes, leadning to missing of 'python.h'. So ganglia configure script could not detect python support.